# Should I install the nvidia drivers for my computer after I've installed bumblebee?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm running an optimus enabled laptop. I installed bumblebee and everything seems to work great. However I'm confused what i should do next. Should i install the nvidia drivers for my computer or would that screw everything up?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the drivers are already installed as a dependency of Bumblebee, no more drivers should be installed after that.

Comment: Then how do i configure nvidia settings? Or are those settings defined by bumblebee?

Comment: Have a look at all [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936), i believe its the best information around about bumblebee and it clearlly says to not install the driver after bumblebee. gl